# Как число long конвертировать в HH:MM:SS?

Tags: java, android, время

Есть число типа `long` со значением `80000`. 
Как его перевести в формат `00:01:20`?

Пробовал этим методом

```
String.format("%1$tM:%1$tS", 80000);
```

Получается `05:01:20`

Откуда эти 5 часов берутся и как их убрать ума не приложу.

Comment: А часовой пояс у вас какой?

Comment: Ну допустим, что `String.format` внутри преобразует `long` в календарь, считая аргумент милисекундами от эпохи (1 января 1970, если не ошибаюсь), и вычисляя локальное время с учетом часового пояса (в Москве - +3 часа, у вас - +5). Но откуда эти часы в форматную строку пролезают?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String.format() конвертирует Long в Date, а new Date(0L) = Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 EET 1970

Попробуйте вот такой способ если в Long секунды

```
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", time / 3600, time / 60 % 60, time % 60);
```

и такой, если миллисекунды

```
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", time / 1000 / 3600, time / 1000 / 60 % 60, time / 1000 % 60);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// создаём переменную типа long   
long someLongInt = 80000L;

//создаём объект класса Calendar и присваиваем ему наше время в миллисекундах
Calendar cal = Calendar.newInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis( someLongInt );

//Используя класс SimpleDateFormat создаём модель отображения времени
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

//выводим отформатированное время в консоль
System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
//выведет 00:01:20
```

Answer (score 1):

Я столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Мне нужно было **long**, перевести в простой **String**, который привычный для обыкновенного юзера в формате **"hh:mm"**. И решил ее следующим кодом (только в этом коде секунды отсуствуют):

```
public String formatLongToStrTime(long time) {
    long mod = time % 3600000;
    long hours = 0;
    long mint = 0;

    if (mod != 0)
        mint = mod / 60000;
    else
        mint = 0;

    hours = time / 3600000;

    String hoursStr = String.valueOf(hours);
    String mintsStr = String.valueOf(mint);
    if (hoursStr.length() == 1)
        hoursStr = "0" + hoursStr;

    if (mintsStr.length() == 1)
        mintsStr = "0" + mintsStr;

    return hoursStr + ":" + mintsStr;
}
```

если метода (функция) получит **34200000**, то есть **time = 34200000**,
то String, который она вернет будет равен: **09:30**